# How do I get a V from a (K,V) node in a hashtable back to the calling method in another class?

Tags: java, casting, nodes

I'm in a data structures class and we have an assignment that includes creating a hash table  for a latin dictionary and on the getDefinition method in the LatinDictionary class (basically a wrapper) it asks for string back after an input of a string like so...

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import data_structures.*;

public class LatinDictionary {
private DictionaryADT<String,String> dictionary;
private int maxSize = DictionaryReader.entries.length;
....
public String getDefinition(String latinWord) {
    return dictionary.getValue(latinWord);
}
```

The getValue method is as follows:

```
package data_structures;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class HashTable <K,V> implements DictionaryADT<K,V>{

private int maxSize,currentSize,tableSize;
private UnorderedList<DictionaryNode<K,V>>[] list;
DictionaryADT<String, String> dictionary;
...
public V getValue(K key){
    int code = hashCode((String)key);
    DictionaryNode temp = new DictionaryNode(key,null);
    if(!list[code].contains(temp))return null;
    DictionaryNode temp2 = new DictionaryNode(null, list[code].find(temp));
    return (V) temp2.value;
}
```

and the find method from the unordered list class is as follows:

```
package data_structures;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class UnorderedList<E> implements Iterable<E>{
public E find(E object) {
    Node<E> current=head;
    Node<E> previous = head;
    Node<E> temp=null;
    while(current!=null && ((Comparable<E>)object).compareTo((current.data))!=0){
        previous=current;
        current=current.next;
        temp=current;
        }

    return temp.data;
    }
```

The dictionaryADT is an interface provided and a specification is that the LatinDictionary will only reference the ADT object and not the hashtable itself.
Additionally, I cannot import java.util.*.
No matter what I try I keep getting a "cannot cast" error or something else depending on what I try but I can't see how to get from a V to a string.
Unfortunately I can't find ANYTHING on the internet relating to self-built hashtables let alone the sort of implementation I have to use here. Anything that has to do with hashtables uses the built-in version and not a self written one, which is of very little use. I have this project due in like 2 weeks but there are 3 other implementations to do after this one! Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you change `DictionaryNode` to use generics so you can move the cast out of this code? I mean are you allowed to change that class.

Comment: no. I can't change dictionary node. :(

Comment: please can you post the full code listing somewhere and share the link? I don't understand how the getValue() method is being used and why it can not return a string. you could forcibly generate a string ofcourse (check of null and then to a toString) but I am not sure if that would be the best idea.

Comment: here you go. http://shorttext.com/46gICb

Comment: Also I tried toString but unfortunately it was the name of the node and not the value. It was weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it....instead of

```
public V getValue(K key){
.....
DictionaryNode temp2 = new DictionaryNode(null, list[code].find(temp));
```

it should be...

```
public V getValue(K key){
....
DictionaryNode temp2 = new DictionaryNode(null, list[code].find(temp).value);
return (V) temp2.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do as @Shakedown, then you could do this:

```
public class LatinDictionary implements HomeworkHashtable<String, String> {

    public String getValue(String key){
        int code = hashCode(key);
        DictionaryNode temp = new DictionaryNode(key,null);
        if(!list[code].contains(temp))return null;
        DictionaryNode temp2 = new DictionaryNode(null, list[code].find(temp));
        return temp2.value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I cannot change the signature of the LatinDictionary class. I added some more code above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see the definition of the Map class, and the unordered list class, but presumably the dictionary is defined as follows

```
public class MyMap<K, V> {
  public V getValue(K key) ...
}
```

If that's the case, in your `LatinDictionary` the back end map (`dictionary`) should be declared with generic types of `String`.

```
public class LatinDictionary {
  private MyMap<String, String> dictionary ...
}
```

In that case, you don't need to convert to `String`, the correct class is gaurenteed to be returned.

[Edit] On another note, if you are writing the implementation of the map, you need to put some thought into hash conflicts.

You could also think about using some standard Java methods, they will generally save you trouble.

```
//This
int code = hashCode((String) key);
//Could become this
int code = key.hashCode();    //Don't need any casts!
```

Comment: `java.util` was never mentioned. From the main part of my answer, you're using standard generics. From the additional edit, you would be using `java.lang.Object` (hashCode method inherited from here), or `java.lang.String` (as the class type you have in your dictionary).

Comment: and I have to create a hashcode from scratch as well. I posted a link to the full code above but here it is again. shorttext.com/46gICb Thanks for your help guys (and gals presumably)!

Comment: also, sorry about the first comment. I had just woken up and misread what you were saying. My fault. and as far as I can tell there is no map class per se, however I cannot be entirely sure. We only briefly went over hashtables in class and neither the book or the notes says much that is useful. He did give us a list of what files need to be created which are:

Comment: LatinDictionary.java; Latin.txt; DictionaryReader.java; DictionaryEntry.java - a wrapper class to provide a single array with keys and values.(provided); DictionaryADT.java - The interface.(provided); BinarySearchTree.java - The binary search tree implementation; HashTable.java - The hash table implementation; UnorderedList.java - A standard unordered linked list used with hash table implementation; OrderedArrayDictionary.java - An ordered array implementations; RedBlackTree.java - The red/black tree implementation. Uses the Java TreeMap class.